# Iterating over mongo documents in swift

Tags: swift, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following code in swift where I can fetch all the documents of car dealers using mongokitten and i'm trying to compare the cares with another list of cars to find perfect matches.

My document looks like this:

```
    ["dealershipUrl": "https://drive.google.com/", "_id": ObjectId("65cbe4dab3305d327a22a8cf"),     "dealershipName": "Toyota456", "cars": [["id": 4537937, "dimension": "hatchback", "quantity": 1, "colour": "Green"], ["id": 4529679, "dimension": "suv", "quantity": 2, "colour": "Green"], ["id":     4164022, "dimension": "RV", "quantity": 1, "colour": "Blue"], "pieceCount": 3, "dealerID": 10713]
```

I want to compare the "cars" list with another list2 to make sure all the items in list2 exist in list1 including the name, colour, and quantity match.

```
     list2 = [car1, car2] 
      static let piece1 = Car(name: "suv", quantity: 1, officialColour: green)    
      static let piece2 = Car( name: "hatchback", quantity: 1, officialColour: green)
```

Here's what i've done so far:

```
     func connectDb() async -> [[String:Any]]?{ 
     do { 
        let connectionString = "mongodb+srv://" 
        let db = try await MongoDatabase.connect(to: connectionString) 
        let collection = db["dealers"] 
        print("Connected to MongoDB") 
        // Fetch the count of documents asynchronously 
        let count = try await collection.count() 
         print("Collection Size: \(count)") 
         let sets = try await collection.find().drain() 
         var formattedSets: [[String: Any]] = [] 
         for set in sets {
            var formattedSet: [String: Any] = [:] 
            for (key, value) in set { 
                formattedSet[key] = value 
            } 
            formattedSets.append(formattedSet) 
          } 
          return formattedSets 
      } catch { 
           print("ERROR CONNECTING TO SERVER: \(error)") 
           return [] 
     } 
     } 

    func findMatches(list2: [car]) async -> [[String: Any]]? { 
        let allSets = await connectDb() 
         var matchingSets: [[String: Any]] = [] 
         if let alldocs = alldocs { 
             for set in allSets { 
                if let pieces = set["cars"] as? [[String: Any]] { // this returns nil for some reason? 
                var allPiecesMatch = true 
                for c in list2 { 
                 let pieceName2 = c.name 
                 let pieceQuantity2 = c.quantity 
                 let pieceColor2 = c.colour         
                 let matching = pieces.first { piece in 
                  guard let docName = piece["dimension"] as! String) as? String, 
                    let docQuantity = piece["quantity"] as? Int, 
                    let docColour = piece["colour"] as? String 
                 else { return false } 
                 return docName == pieceName2 && docColour == pieceColor2 && docQuantity <= pieceQuantity2 
          } 
          if matchingPiece == nil { 
                  allPiecesMatch = false break 
          } 
         } 
         if allPiecesMatch { print("FOUND ONE") //matchingSets.append(set) } 
     } 
     }
     }
```

when i print set["cars"] it works but when i print:
let pieces = set["cars"] as? [[String: Any]]
it returns nil

also the type of set["cars"] is optional[Any]